# C# lambda expression && operators

Tags: c#, lambda, operators

I have this code here :

```
public Model.task GetDelete(int qno , int aid , int tid)
{
   return context.questions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.QuestionNo = qno & a.ActivityID == aid & a.TaskID == tid);
}
```

I need to fit all 3 ids, there is an error above, I am new to programming , how can I do this error free? Basically I need check for 3 ids, is this possible? There is error saying

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Comment: Why is the code using `&` instead of `&&`?

Comment: Also, you are missing a `=` from the first check. You need `==`, you have just `=`.

Answer (score 5):

You have assigment operator inside lambda `=`, you need to use equality operator `==`, like:

```
context.questions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.QuestionNo == qno & a.ActivityID == aid & a.TaskID == tid);
                                            //here ^^
```

You get an error:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

because assignment operator returns the `int` value in your case, while equality operator on the right expects bool.

Usage of short-circuit operator `&&` is optional here, they won't change
the behaviour of your lambda, **if** your properties don't have any
[side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) and they return primitive types or types, that don't override `==` operator introducing side effects.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `&&` instead of `&`

`&&` is

> conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND

`&` is

> For integral types, & computes the logical bitwise AND of its
>   operands. For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its
>   operands; that is`

Comment: i was trying && as well , it doesn't work too , same error

Comment: replace `=` with `==`